# Iterate a list in jsp and construct a single Message

Tags: jsp, iterator

I need to iterate a list which has properties like name, age, hobby etc and I need to show it as a single message.

```
Student.java

Private String name;
Private long age;
Private String hobby;
```

I can iterate the list and show multiple messages

1st Student name is John age 17 hobby is cricket

2nd student name is Peter age 18 hobby is football

but I need something like this

1st Student name is John age 17 hobby is cricket , 2nd student name is Peter age 18 hobby is football and 3rd student name is Mike age 19 hobby is Music

Answer (score 0):

You can simply iterate list and create a single message, As you mentioned that you're able to print 1st student,2nd student, Hence I did not mentioned that logic here.
It is just about using **comma** and **and** keyword at right place.

```
String singleMsg="";
for (int i = 0; i < studentList.size(); i++) { 
  Student student = studentList.get(i);
    if(i==studentList.size()-1)
       singleMsg +="and Student name is "+student.getName() +"age 
                   "+student.getAge() +"hobby is "+student.getHobby();
     else if(singleMsg.isEmpty())
       singleMsg +="1st Student name is "+student.getName() +"age 
                   "+student.getAge() +"hobby is "+student.getHobby();
      else
         singleMsg +=", Student name is "+student.getName() +"age 
                     "+student.getAge() +"hobby is "+student.getHobby();
 }
out.print(singleMsg );
```